# RapidMiner Text Processing: How To write ngrams to file

Tags: rapidminer

How can I write ngrams extracted from Text to a new XLS or CSV file?

The process I created is shown below. I would like to know how to connect the `Write Document` utility and at which level. In the `Main Process` or in the `Vector Creation`? Which pipe goes where?

**Screenshot Main Process:**
[image]

**Screenshot Vector Creation process:**

[image]

**Screenshot ngrams produced:**

[image]

**Screenshot Write Document operator:**

[image]

I am using RapidMiner Studio 6.0.003 Community Edition

**EDIT** Solution:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two outputs from the `Process Documents from Files` operator. The top one is an example set and will correspond to the document vector generated by the operator. The bottom one is a word list that contains all the different words, including n-grams, that form the attributes within the document vector.

To write the word list to a file, you have to convert it to an example set using the `WordList to Data` operator. The example set that is produced can then be written to CSV or XLSX using the `Write CSV` or `Write Excel` operators.